# Getting php session value in jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery

Am creating a page in jquery mobile whereby a jquery function is supposed to check for the set php session variable but i get an error of syntax error in the console.

The code:

```
$(document).on("pageshow","#schoolperformance", function(){ 

var sessName = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['schoolname']); ?>';

 alert(sessName);

});
```

When i check the value of $_SESSION['schoolname'] in a normal way via a raw php script it returns a value of the session.

THE FILE IS A JAVASCRIPT FILE that is saved as a .js file

Comment: why do you json_encode it ?

Comment: After json_encode(sessName) i get an error of unexpected identifier pointing to the json_encode

Comment: Is the code in a .php file?

Comment: no its  a .js file

Comment: You cannot perform `PHP` in `.JS` files

Comment: No wonder it doesn't get parsed. You need to change the extension to .php and put the following at the top of the file: `<?php session_start(); header('Content-Type: text/javascript;'); ?>`.

Comment: The webserver hands the file only to the PHP parser if the extension is .php. If the extension is not .php and you want that the file gets parsed, you need to tell the webserver to explicitely to handover the file to the PHP parser.

Comment: will it also work for the other javascript files since am calling it after jquery mobile.min.js in the jquery-mobile page

Comment: No, you need to change the extension of every javascript file and include the code posted above if you want to use PHP and read session variables.

Comment: Thanks for the help it finally works..God bless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the single quote at this line

```
var sessName = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['schoolname']); ?>';
```

To double quotes

```
var sessName = "<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['schoolname']); ?>";
```

The `sessName` variable string is breaking up by using single quotes surrounding the `string` and `php` variable. because its stops right at `['`

**UPDATE:**

As you say in your comments that you trying to perform PHP in `.JS` files that is totally wrong, because for PHP to work you need to use `.PHP` file extensions not `.JS` extensions

Comment: after changing to double quotes  and performing alert(sessName); it alerts the part { "<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['schoolname']); ?>"} as a string.

Comment: Thanks your ans is correct the problem was that it was a js file not a php file